# trouble at designing layout of web page

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-design, frontend

I am trying to display sidebar on left and main dynamic content on right side. Here,  I am giving `col-sm-3` for sidebar and rest (`col-sm-9`) for the content.
The problem I have faced here is that my sidebar doesnot fit exactly on `col-sm-3` so small gap (white part in image below) is seen in between the sidebar and the main content.
[image]

If I decreased the grid of sidebar to `col-sm-2` then the main content moves back to sidebar and some content gets hidden. Somewhere on sidebar I have used z-index as 1 to manage background image, opacity and content as it seems.

How can I make the sidebar to exactly fit in the grid on left side and dynamic content on right without such white blank vertical space in between?

I also tried using table but while doing so my content moved back of the sidebar. What's the solution?

my `home.handlebars` is like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    {{> home/sidebar}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color: #EEF1F3; ">
                    {{{ body }}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my `sidebar.handlebars` is like

```
<div class="wrapper" >

      <div class="sidebar sidebar-overwrite" data-color="azure" data-background-color="blue" data-image="../../../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">

        <div class="mysidebar-wrapper"> </div>

          <div class="logo" >
            <a href="#"  class="simple-text logo-normal NSC-link">
              <img src="images/nepathya-logo.jpg" class="img img-responsive nepathya-logo" height="100px"><br>
              <b>Nepathya Student Council</b>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">

              <li class="nav-item active" id="nav-item-overwrite">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">
                  <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">home</i>
                  <p class="sidebar-list-items">Home</p>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item" id="nav-item-overwrite">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/login">
                  <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">person</i>
                  <p class="sidebar-list-items">Login/Register</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <!-- your sidebar here -->

              <li class="nav-item" id="nav-item-overwrite">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="">
                    <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">contact_support</i>
                    <p class="sidebar-list-items">Questions Collections</p>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" id="nav-item-overwrite">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#0">
                    <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">book</i>
                    <p class="sidebar-list-items">Solutions</p>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#0">
                    <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">receipt</i>
                    <p class="sidebar-list-items">Notes</p>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" id="nav-item-overwrite">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#0">
                      <i class="material-icons material-icon-overwrite">cloud_upload</i>
                      <p class="sidebar-list-items">Upload</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>


</div>
```

my `sidebar.css` is like

```
   .sidebar-overwrite {
    z-index: 1;
   }

   .sidebar-overwrite .mysidebar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: url("../images/sidebar-1.jpg") center center;
      opacity: .1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }

   .sidebar .logo .simple-text {
    white-space: normal !important;
   }
  .sidebar-list-items {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .material-icon-overwrite {
    color: black !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bootstrap default padding and margin issue. Zero out your padding and margins for the 3 and 9 columns, and add and take away accordingly.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style"padding:0; margin:0;">
                {{> home/sidebar}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding:0; margin:0; background-color: #EEF1F3; ">
                {{{ body }}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I edited my answer with the code that should zero out your margins & padding and make everything fit flush. If it doesn't work then you have some other issues.

Comment: @John try to send a link to the site or JS FIDDLE, or snippet with all the code  so we can see what the problem is and see the code in action.

Comment: I have set margin and padding to 0px. It does not work too.

Comment: https://github.com/pradip503/nsc-project please fork to this and help me.

Comment: Put it on a JSFiddle.